# Changing the Speed of a motor in Processing/box2D

Tags: processing, box2d

I've been making some simple games using processing and box2D using The Nature of Code as a resource.

My problem is I have gotten to a point where I have these windmills that go clockwise/counterclockwise depending on the speed of the motor (I am using `PI/2` and `-PI*2`). I want to have it so that the user can change this speed from positive and negative by pressing a key or mouse button. Looking around online people and the box2D documentation are saying to use the function `void SetMotorSpeed(float speed);`, however I am not having luck figuring out how to implement this. I've tried a few ways I can think but no luck.

Currently I have this in my main file ("s" is the name of the instance of the windmill):

```
// Click the mouse to switch speed of motor
void mousePressed() {
    s.SetMotorSpeed(s.speed);
}
```

And I have this in the file for the windmill:

```
//Set Motor Speed
void SetMotorSpeed(float speed){
     speed = speed * -1;
}
```

This doesn't work though.

I'm fairly new to coding and this is my first post on stack-overflow so my apologies if I have done anything wrong in how I'm asking or presenting this question. I'm open to suggestions both code and etiquette wise!

Here is the code for the entire windmill:

```
class Seesaw {

    // object is two boxes and one joint
    
    RevoluteJoint joint;
    // float speed = PI*2;
    Box box1;
    Box box2;
    float speed = PI*2;

    Seesaw(float x, float y) {
        // Initialize locations of two boxes
        box1 = new Box(x, y-20, 120, 10, false); 
        box2 = new Box(x, y, 10, 40, true); 

        // Define joint as between two bodies
        RevoluteJointDef rjd = new RevoluteJointDef();
        Vec2 offset = box2d.vectorPixelsToWorld(new Vec2(0, 60));
        rjd.initialize(box1.body, box2.body, box1.body.getWorldCenter());

        // Turning on a motor (optional)
        rjd.motorSpeed = PI*2;       // how fast?
        rjd.maxMotorTorque = 1000.0; // how powerful?
        rjd.enableMotor = true;      // is it on?
        // Create joint
        joint = (RevoluteJoint) box2d.world.createJoint(rjd);
    }

    // Turn the motor on or off
    void toggleMotor() {
        joint.enableMotor(!joint.isMotorEnabled());
    }

    boolean motorOn() {
        return joint.isMotorEnabled();
    }
    
    void SetMotorSpeed(float speed){
        speed = -speed;
    }

    void display() {
        box2.display();
        box1.display();

        // Draw anchor just for debug
        Vec2 anchor = box2d.coordWorldToPixels(box1.body.getWorldCenter());
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        stroke(0);
        ellipse(anchor.x, anchor.y, 4, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a working example? Something which show what you mean when we copy it into an IDE. Ideally, the minimum needed code to avoid cluttering both this post and our minds. btw welcome to SO! Your post is good, but lacks information about the code itself, as your implementation can be about anything, and we cannot guess (I mean, I could chase it in The Nature of Code but it would make me work instead of you).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response! I edited the question to include the code for the Seesaw object. Not sure if that is enough to go on, let me know. I didn't want to just paste the whole project in there and make it a giant post unless that's what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

The change in speed should be communicated to the joint. Try this:

```
void SetMotorSpeed(float speed) {
     s.joint.setMotorSpeed(speed); // edited, processing/java uses camel-case
}
```

you might also be a bit more careful about naming variables. In your original post you use the same name for the local variable and the member variable, which has not the wanted effect. Most people use some naming convention for member variable to avoid this kind of very common error. Like for instance have all member variables all start with "_"

```
void SetMotorSpeed(float speed) {
    _speed = -speed; // speed is local!
}
```

Comment: With a little tweaking, this worked.! I was trying to use rjd.SetMotorSpeed(), when I should have been using joint.setMotorSpeed(). I don't quite get yet why in the constructor you set speed with rjd. but then to change it you use joint., but at least it is working and I can learn from there. I used your suggestion and still was struggling because the first letter of the function was capitalized. I thought that was odd when I first started working on this, but the documentation even has it as SetMotorSpeed(), but it's setMotorSpeed(). Thanks to everyone for the suggestions/comments/edits!

Comment: you are correct, it should be lowercase, since it is more common in Java, as explained here: http://www.jbox2d.org/. The original box2d in cpp uses uppercase, and so is the documentation I looked https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_dynamics.html.

Comment: And here is why changing rjd had ho effect: In your constructor, the joint definition is passed to the world object to create the joint. The world object does not keep a reference to the joint definition, instead it copies all to its internal structures. This is just the way box2d is designed. Your idea was actually not bad and other libraries would work that way.